# Radio button selection for paypal form issue

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, calculated-field

need your help

So i have a paypal form which also has two radio buttons. One with a shipping value, and one without. Here is the link to the actual form
http://www.topchoicedata.com/test.php

What i want to happen is that if a person selected the first radio box("$19.99 Shipping – DATABASE SENT ON CD ROM"), then 19.99 would automatically be added to the "hdwppamount" amount which is set at $175, so when the person press's "pay now", it will make a grand total of $194.99 on the paypal page.

And if the person selected the second option instead("FREE SHIPPING – DATABASE SENT VIA EMAIL") instead, then of course no value is added to the "hdwppamount" amount and $175 would be the total for the paypal page.

Now the code does work if the person chooses on or the other options, and then does not alternate between the radio buttons deciding which one they choose. So its kind of buggy because if i choose the first option, then decided the second option, and so on and so forth alternating, i either get an error page or if i did choose the free option, the 19.99 still gets added.

I need so that if the first option is chosen, then the 19.99 gets added, and if the second option chosen, then nothing is added.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!--------------------HTML Form---------------------_

  <form action="PPPaymentForm/PPPaymentForm.php"  method="post" name="topchoiceform" id="topchoiceform">
    <input placeholder="Company Name" type="text" name="companyname" required>
    <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="first_name" required>
    <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="last_name" required>
    <input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    <input placeholder="Address" type="text" name="address1" required>

    <input name="shipping" class="shipping" type="radio" id="shipping" checked/>
    <label class="shippingcheck">$19.99 Shipping – DATABASE SENT ON CD ROM </label>
     <br>
    <input name="shipping" class="shipping" type="radio" id="noshipping"/>
    <label class="shippingcheck">FREE SHIPPING – DATABASE SENT VIA EMAIL</label>

    <br>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Pay Now</button>



    <!-------------Paypal Part------------->
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwtablename" id="hdwtablename" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwppproductname" id="hdwppproductname" value="Basic Plan 175">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwppamount" id="hdwppamount" value="175">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwppcurrency" id="hdwppcurrency" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwpplanguage" id="hdwpplanguage" value="en_US">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwok" id="hdwok" value="http://www.topchoicedata.com/paymentmadethanks.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwemail" id="hdwemail" value="mauriceflopez+gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwnook" id="hdwnook" value="http://">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwactivation_email" id="hdwactivation_email" value="email">
    <input type="hidden" name="plan" id="plan" value="$175">
    <input type="hidden" name="shippingchoosen" id="shippingchoosen" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="shippingnumber" id="shippingnumber" value="">
  </form>
```

PHP

```
<script>

$('#shipping').change(function(){

    var hdwppamount = Number($("#hdwppamount").val())

    var shippingcost = 19.99;



     if (this.checked) {

        $("#hdwppamount").val(hdwppamount+shippingcost)

     } else {

        $("#hdwppamount").val(hdwppamount-shippingcost)

     }

})

</script>
```

Comment: You could to be safe try doing  $("#hdwppamount").val(+hdwppamount +  +shippingcost)

Comment: What you have labeled as PHP above is actually JavaScript. I've removed the _php_ tag here because its irrelevant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With radio you may have only one of them checked at a time. This means you have to test which one is checked in a specified moment (i.e.: change event).

I changed the input field hdwppamount from hidden to text in the snippet to make clear the behaviour.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#shipping, #noshipping').on('change', function(){
    var hdwppamount = Number($("#hdwppamount").val());
    var shippingcost = 19.99;
    if (this.id == 'noshipping') { // shipping unchecked
      $("#hdwppamount").val(hdwppamount-shippingcost);
    } else { // shipping checked
      $("#hdwppamount").val(hdwppamount+shippingcost);
    }
  });
  // initialize the field with the correct value
  $("#hdwppamount").val('194.99');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<form action="PPPaymentForm/PPPaymentForm.php"  method="post" name="topchoiceform" id="topchoiceform">
    <input placeholder="Company Name" type="text" name="companyname" required>
    <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="first_name" required>
    <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="last_name" required>
    <input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    <input placeholder="Address" type="text" name="address1" required>

    <input name="shipping" class="shipping" type="radio" id="shipping" checked/>
    <label class="shippingcheck">$19.99 Shipping – DATABASE SENT ON CD ROM </label>
    <br>
    <input name="shipping" class="shipping" type="radio" id="noshipping" />
    <label class="shippingcheck">FREE SHIPPING – DATABASE SENT VIA EMAIL</label>

    <br>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Pay Now</button>



    <!-------------Paypal Part------------->
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwtablename" id="hdwtablename" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwppproductname" id="hdwppproductname" value="Basic Plan 175">
    <input type="text" name="hdwppamount" id="hdwppamount" value="175">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwppcurrency" id="hdwppcurrency" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwpplanguage" id="hdwpplanguage" value="en_US">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwok" id="hdwok" value="http://www.topchoicedata.com/paymentmadethanks.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwemail" id="hdwemail" value="mauriceflopez+gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwnook" id="hdwnook" value="http://">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwactivation_email" id="hdwactivation_email" value="email">
    <input type="hidden" name="plan" id="plan" value="$175">
    <input type="hidden" name="shippingchoosen" id="shippingchoosen" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="shippingnumber" id="shippingnumber" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!